# Button in iPhoto that reveal another sliding toolbar

Tags: ios, ios5, toolbar, iphoto, uitoolbaritem

How can I develop a toolbar like this one, with a button that when it's pressed reveals another toolbar (sliding on top of the current one)? This is a screenshot from the iPhoto application from Apple.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKYZq.png

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't have any idea how that is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using the following (**Disclaimer: THIS MAY VIOLATE THE HIG!**):

1. I added a new, basic UIViewController.
2. I added a UIToolbar to the view of the UIViewController. I connected this UIToolbar to a property in my UIViewController named "BaseToolbar".
3. To "BaseToolbar", I added a button. I connected this button to an IBAction called "AddPressed:" in my UIViewController.
4. I added a UIToolbar to the UIViewController's xib, ***BUT NOT ON THE UIViewController's view.*** I just added it onto the design surface. I connected this UIToolbar to a property in my UIViewController named "SecondToolbar".
5. To "SecondToolbar", I added a button. I connected this button to an IBAction called "TrashPressed:" in my UIViewController.

I used the following code:

```
- (IBAction)AddPressed:(id)sender {
    CGRect secondCurrRect = [[self SecondToolbar] frame];
    [[self SecondToolbar] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1 * secondCurrRect.size.height, secondCurrRect.size.width, secondCurrRect.size.height)];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self SecondToolbar]];
    [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:[self SecondToolbar]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^(void){
                         [[self SecondToolbar] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, secondCurrRect.size.width, secondCurrRect.size.height)];
                     }];
}
- (IBAction)TrashPressed:(id)sender {
    CGRect secondCurrRect = [[self SecondToolbar] frame];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^(void){
                         [[self SecondToolbar] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1 * secondCurrRect.size.height, secondCurrRect.size.width, secondCurrRect.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [[self SecondToolbar] removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Using that code, the new UIToolbar slides on/off ***ON TOP OF*** the "base" UIToolbar.

---

***Edit/Update***

Let's try a different tactic. 
**(This assumes you're adding the `UIToolbar` objects to your xib at design time)**

1. Add Toolbar #1 (the one that is always on-screen) to the top of the view and position it like you want.
2. Add Toolbar #2 (the one that slides on/of) underneath Toolbar #1 and build it out with the buttons you want.
3. Put the following line of code into your `-(void)viewDidLoad` method (this will move the second toolbar off-screen):

---

```
[[self Toolbar2] setFrame:
    CGRectMake(0,                                    // origin.x
               -[[self Toolbar2] frame].size.height, // origin.y
               [[self Toolbar2] frame].size.width,   // size.width (remains the same)
               [[self Toolbar2] frame].size.height)  // size.height (remains the same)
];
```

Then, use the code from above, but skip the calls to `addSubview:` and `removeFromSuperview`.

Does that make sense now?

Comment: So, typically in Interface Builder, you have a main view and you add all of your subViews to that. It doesn't have to be that way, however. You can add whatever you want ***outside*** of the main view. It shows up in the "Objects" hierarchy on the same level as the other views, and they are, in essence, unrelated. However, you can still create IBOutlet/IBAction connections. This way, the 2nd `UIToolbar` is unrelated to your main view until you programmatically call 'addSubview`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add the 2nd `UIToolbar` to your main view and position it so that it's off the screen. Then, you could simply manage/animate its frame to make it appear/disappear. I like to truly have it not on the screen, though, which is why I call `addSubview:` and `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: either way i can't put the second toolbar above the first one

Comment: i have my first toolbar in a UITableViewController. I think that is the problem

Comment: with a uitableviewcontroller i can do this? or i need to change to a uiviewcontroller?

Comment: You probably want a `UIView` container that holds both the `UIToolbar` and the `UITableView`.

Comment: No problem. If it **was** helpful, can I get an up vote and an accepted answer? ;-) Thanks!